# What is the performance trade off with choice of cloud platform for hosting snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

A Snowflake account can be hosted on any of AWS, GCP, or Azure.

Should I decide on the cloud platform based on where my application consuming the data will be hosted?

Will it **perform (in terms of network latency)** better if my application and snowflake both are on same cloud platform or it does not really make a difference?

NOTE : Intention is purely in terms of Network latency and not COST. w.r.t to cost, From the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/billing-data-transfer.html#data-transfer-billing-use-cases) I understand it's agnostic of the cloud provider and region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's surely perform better in terms of network latency if your application and snowflake both are on same cloud platform.

There could be different network latencies between regions for same Cloud provider:

https://docs.aviatrix.com/HowTos/inter_region_latency.html#aws-inter-region-latency

Answer (score 0):

Yes Network latency will be definitely better as they will be on the same region if your application and warehouse are on the same cloud platform.

One other benefit I can think of using aws(for example) for both the application and snowflake is then your backend data is all on s3 and as a developer I find that easier to debug in case any issues.

Also snowflake stage creation can be easier with either keys or integration objects.

I don't know how that will play if you have two different cloud platforms for your application and data warehouse.